# How to find Lon. and Lat. of a field by having a few sample GPS points?

Tags: matlab, gps, interpolation

I'm working on a field and for some reasons I need to find the exact Longitude and Latitude for different points on the field. Please have a look at the attached picture. Let's say I have such a field and I have divided it into 1000 different cells. Because the field is huge, it's not possible for me to capture Long. and Lat using GPS for all cells. I was thinking it might be possible to capture GPS data at some points (e.g. at cells number 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, ...) and then find others by interpolation or something like that. Do you have any idea how to do this? How can I find exact Long. and Lat for all cells by having some GPS sample points? Do you think using a simple MATLAB interpolation is a good option? Thanks in advance for your suggestions and ideas.
[image: Sample map]

Comment: Yes, it's very suitable to use interpolation here.  You're looking specifically for 2D interpolation.  Consult the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I deleted the old question before posting this because didn't get any answer.